# Removing Empty Elements from a Vector of Strings

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm attempting to make a small program that processes INI files, for use in a later project, first by reducing its size once loaded into memory. Thus,

where vLine is a vector containing the file contents

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vLine.size(); i++)
{
   if (!vLine[i].find(';', 0))
   {
       vLine[i].erase();
   }
}
```

Upon printing vLine, I'll be left with spaces where once a line beginning with a semi-colon existed, such as

```
1.    
2. property
3. property
4. 
5. property
```

Using resize() appears to remove the last element from the list rather than remove these empty portions. The same problem exists where I remove lines that only contain whitespace with erase().

Is it possible to remove these empty elements while preserving the order of vLine?

(Apologies for not using iterators in this.)

Comment: Re: (Apologies for not using iterators in this.) - Why not use iterators?

Comment: Lack of knowledge regarding their proper use. It seems (seemed?) possible to do this without them.

Comment: You can remove the lines from the vector rather than just erasing the string's contents (which is what `vLine[i].erase()` does, no? Call `vLine.erase()` since that erases from the `vector`. Then rewrite the file out. An idiomatic way to do this is C++'s [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), though you would want to use `std::remove_if` from `<algorithm>` to use a conditional.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This:

```
vLine[i].erase();
```

does not erase `vLine[i]` from the vector. The expression `vLine[i]` returns a reference to the element at index `i`. So assuming that `vLine` is of type `std::vector<std::string>`, the function call `erase()` actually calls `string::erase()` on the element, not `vector::erase()` on the vector. All you're doing is making that particular element blank.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
vLine.erase(vLine.begin() + i);
```

This actually removes the element from the vector. Now, this does invalidate all current iterators to the vector, and the indices won't be right anymore. This is a situation where you really need to use iterators.

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = vLine.begin();
while(i != vLine.end())
{
    if(i->find(';', 0) != std::string::npos)
    {
        i = vLine.erase(i);
    }
    else
    {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

But there's an even easier way to do this: use the standard algorithm [`std::remove_if()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) with a functor then call `vLine.erase()`.

```
struct HasSemicolon
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& s)
    {
        return s.find(';', 0) != std::string::npos;
    }
};

// ...

vLine.erase(std::remove_if(vLine.begin(), vLine.end(), HasSemicolon()), vLine.end());
```

If you can use a C++11 compiler, then you can also use lambda expressions to be even more concise.

Comment: Much obliged, In Silico. I'll take the time to learn iterators and alter my application accordingly.

Comment: Could you add an example using C++11 lambdas? I've been trying to figure it out for the better part of an hour now but I'm horrible at reading C++ docs.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove has an example with a lambda.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is in your logic for removing the elements. When you come across an element at index `i` that you want to erase, you clear its value, but you do not remove it from the vector.

The standard and simple way to do what you want to do is `std::remove_if`:

```
vLine.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        vLine.begin(),
        vLine.end(),
        [](std::string const& s) { return s.size() != 0 && s.front() == ';'; }),
    vLine.end());
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the erase/remove-idiom, preferably with a lambda from C++11:

```
foo.erase(std::remove_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), 
                         [](const std::string& s) 
                         { return s.find(';', 0); }));
```

Comment: I think `{ return s.find(';', 0); }));` needs to be: `{ return s.find(';', 0); }), foo.end());` Otherwise the space does not appear to be deallocated from foo. At least this is the result I got. @Mankarse's answer (basically the same) seemed to do the job! : )

Answer (score 2):

With C++20 you can use [std::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) which is equivalent to the erase-remove idiom.

```
std::erase_if(vLine, [](auto&& str){
    return str.find(';', 0) != std::string::npos;
})
```

Comment: This answer was a total win for me today.